# Is possible to unzip multiple WARs from different repositories in a similar destination?

Tags: gradle, unzip, unpack

Using Gradle I try to unzip multiple WARs from different local repositories into the same destination but I cannot find a way.

According to several solutions using zipTree(object), I did something like....

```
task unpackingWar(type:Copy){ 
   destinationDir = file("$buildDir/generated-resources/unpack/static") 
   includes = ["**","*.jsp"] 
   includeEmptyDirs = false  
  for (webWar in configurations.webWarUnpacking.files){
       from{
          zipTree(webWar) 
      } 
}
```

The point is this solution is always overwritting the destination directory with last WAR of configuration list. I would like to unpack the whole list of WARs into the destination directory.

I thought in creating a ZIP with all WARs and unpacking them but I wanted to develop a more elegant way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way using ant.unzip(), worked for me.

```
tasks.register('unpackWar') {
doLast {
    mkdir("build/generated-reources/unpack/static")
    for( webWar in configurations.webWarUnpacking.files) {
        ant.unzip(src: webWar, dest:"build/generated-reources/unpack/static", overwrite:"false") {
            patternset( ) {
                include( name: '**' )
                exclude( name: '**/*.jsp')
            }
            mapper(type:"identity")
        }
    }
}
```

}